# Rounding up the no input to the multiple of 12 and then using it in further calculations in python

Tags: python

okay i am asked to create a python program  in which the program asks the customers name and the amount of eggs and then print out the summary with name, total price, total no eggs and total no of dozens.

For example- If the input for the no of eggs is 13 it should count it as 2 dozens and will cost the customer for 2 dozens. So this what i have done so far.

But the *problem is the code only works with multiples of 12*. So i want it to work with any number like if we input any number it will automatically round up the input for the order.

For example if I input 13 it should go to 24 and will count as 2 dozens with the price of two dozens.

Comment: Divide with `12.0`. `ceil` it, then multiply with `12`

Comment: DONT deface your question

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function that will give you the rounded up dozens:

```
>>> def roundedUpDozens(n):
...   return (n + 11) // 12
...
>>> roundedUpDozens(12)
1
>>> roundedUpDozens(13)
2
>>> roundedUpDozens(14)
2
>>> roundedUpDozens(0)
0
>>>
```

Comment: so what do i do if want to call the function

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
fullDozens = totalOrdered / 12
if totalOrdered % 12: # round up to the next dozen
    totalDozens = fullDozens + 1
else: # even number of dozens
    totalDozens = fullDozens
```

Answer (score 0):

Three different approaches (1 and 3 are essentially the same):

```
def f1(x):
    return (x // 12 + (1 if x % 12 else 0)) * 12

def f2(x):
    import math
    return math.ceil(x / 12.0) * 12

def f3(x):
    n,r = divmod(x, 12)
    if r: n += 1
    return n * 12

for i in [11,12,13]:
    print(i,":", f1(i), f2(i), f3(i))
```

Output:

```
11 : 12 12 12
12 : 12 12 12
13 : 24 24 24  # At 13, the output jumps from 1 dozen to 2 dozen.
```